# Set a background for a specific <th> column in jquery Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to set a background color for a specific TH but have not found a simple way to do this in the settings of DataTables.
I use only the opening and closing tag of the table. The remainder with DataTables.

```
<table id="myTable"></table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    oTable = $("#myTable").dataTable({

        "aaData"      : myTableJsonData, //Working perfect
        "bProcessing" : true,
        "bJQueryUI"   : true,
        "sDom"        : "<'H'f>rt<'F'i>",       

        "aoColumnDefs" : [
            { "aTargets":[0], "mDataProp":"id",   "sTitle":"ID" },
            { "aTargets":[1], "mDataProp":"name", "sTitle":"NAME", "sClass":"name" },
            { "aTargets":[2], "mDataProp":"city", "sTitle":"CITY" }
        ]       
    });
});
</script>
```

The attribute "sClass" does not fit in my case because I don't want change all the TD's.. only the TH.
I tried something simple like:

```
// Not work because looks like it is overwritten by jquery UI theme
$("#myTable").closest("thead").find(".name").addClass("bgGreen");
```

If I set something like this, works fine .. but wanted to avoid that.

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th></th>
           <th class="bgGreen"></th>
           <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the index of the column (number 2, from what I can see), you can use that to apply the `bgGreen` class by selecting the th with [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/). (There are [other](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) [ways](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the nth element in a list, this is one example.)

```
// Child column number known in advance (1-based)
$("#myTable")
  .find("thead th:nth-child(2)")
  .addClass("bgGreen");
```

If you don't know the column number in advance, there are ways to get the number by finding a `<td class="name">` and figuring out in which column it is. A possible solution might involve a simple loop over the first row in `<tbody>` and check for the `name` class. Then that number can be used in the query above, or something similar.

Comment: Hello Joel! I applied your solution in an HTML table "normal" and works fine, but not in my current case with Datatables. It's not working because apparently that `<th>` is not found in DOM while the table is being generated via Datatables API with data from Json.

Comment: Also tried using the "fnInitComplete" of datatables and still does not work hehe

Comment: @EvertonZamignanPabon: In that case, why not run the `bgGreen` code in one of [dataTable's callbacks](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks)? `fnInitComplete` looks suitable, since it runs after fetching the data. Just copy the example and replace the alert.

Comment: @EvertonZamignanPabon: sorry, misread that last comment about `fnInitComplete`. If the callback doesn't work, I'm not sure what to do. Another callback perhaps, but that's pretty much it.

Comment: I had tried it too and did not work :).
I'm temporarily setting the classes for my TH's directly in HTML, until a native option  DataTables be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

if it is just background color why not use

```
$("#myTable")
  .find("thead th:nth-child(2)").css('background-color', 'green');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add .bgGreen to the 2nd `<th>` with the javascript below.  The CSS definition for .bgGreen needs `!impotant` to prevent the default theme from overriding .bgGreen.  You can also use straight CSS3 to accomplish the same results.

```js
$('#myTable > thead > tr > th:nth-child(2)').addClass("bgGreen");
```

```css
.bgGreen {
    background : green !important;
}
#myTable > thead > tr > th:nth-child(2){
    background : green !important;
}
```